# Creating Twitter-style routes with Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I make Twitter-style routes with Rails3?

I've tried the following:

```
match ':username', :controller => "users", :action => "show"
match ':username/:controller(/:action(/:id))', :path_prefix => '/:username'
```

**EDIT**

After some more digging through the docs, I did this and it seems to work:

```
scope '/:username' do
  resources :clubs
end
```

What is the "scope" method exactly and is there an automatic way of generating link_to URLs in my views?

Answer (score 0):

The following matcher will match `/dhh/update/1`

```
match ':username/update/:id' => 'updates#show'
```

`'update#show'` is new in Rails 3 and is the short version of `:controller => 'updates', :action => 'show'`

Comment: That looks fine, but what about having multiple controllers and actions? Like /username/controller1 or /username/controller2/action3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `clubs_path(:username => 'bob')`.